# How do i mark as selected a specific option from a select which his options are loaded depending of an input number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

take your time to read my explanation and ask me if i didn't explain myself well, thanks.

Don't mind how i print whith php, it it okay this way, this is a php setting.

i have in a template an input number that the client will fill with an amount of pallets, in the same template i have a table with as many tr as boxes the order has.

so, there are as many selects as tr, because it is used to assign the box to a pallet.

When the process is done i have the info in my database and if the client enters again he will need to have all the data in place, so the input number is filled and that fills all the selects with the amount of otions as the input, ok.

the fill process is made with jquery.

in the template, i have only this to make the select

```
<td><select class="pallets_assign" name="boxes[<?=$box;?>][which_pallet]"></select></td>
```

**UPDATE**:
to load the options in the selects i use this inside a document ready :

```
var someone = function() {
    var something = function(from_pallets, to_pallets) {
        var qty = $(from_pallets);
        var select = $(to_pallets);
        var update = function() {
            select.empty();
            for (var i = 1; i <= qty.val(); i++) {
                select.append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
            }
        };

        qty.on('change', update);
        update();
    }
});
```

form the tamplate i call it like this:

```
var init = function() {
    someone.something('#total_pallets', '.pallets_assign');
};
```

total_pallets is the id of the input number

My question is: how do i mark as selected the option which value i have stored in my database if i don't have the options created when the DOM is loaded but when that input number changed?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: at first i put the php tag because i thought i need to make some workaround mixing javascript and php but people didn't take it so well. :(

Comment: select should already have a "selected=true" option in the list.

Comment: before making a judgement can you fully read the question please? i don't think i deserve the negative points

Comment: It hasn't been taken too well as it is off topic for the site - too broad.  Have a look into ajax - it allows you to load stuff from your db using js.  Also if you are wanting us to read the question carefully, then you need to read the rules of this site carefully.

Comment: @burhancerit the thing is that the options are created dinamycally, that's why i don't have a sleected option

Comment: If you want to get real answers please avoid sentences like _Don't mind how i print whith php, it it okay this way._ - **We must understand the whole context** in order to help, show us more relevant code and then your question should probably be reopened (Then i'll also retract my negative votes)

Comment: @Pete but i need to have also the other options in the select as the client may need to reassign a box to a different pallet

Comment: @AlonEitan the way i print in php is a setting of php that is not something to be angry i think, either way, i'm gonna make an update whith how i load the options

Comment: @iscato I wasn't being angry - I put it in bold to highlight the main reason I chose to cast a close vote on your question. This is not personal in any way :)

Comment: @AlonEitan sry i didn't understand what you meant

Comment: @iscato You must understand that stackoverflow community is very strict about the rules of asking question, if you fail to provide the relevant part then you're probably doomed to get your question downvoted and/or closed. BTW, you can't call that function you just added on your last edit, you should name it `function myFunc(from_pallets, to_pallets) { ,,, }` and call it `myFunc(from_pallets, to_pallets);` or self-invoke it `(function(from_pallets, to_pallets) { ... })(from_pallets, to_pallets)`

Comment: @AlonEitan i can not share the entirety of the code, but i can assure you that this works, this is the process to fill  the options in the select, this is only related to the question because of this action, what i need is to find a solution for when i already have this options loaded. i did an update with a similar but not the same thing as my code to be more explanatory

Comment: @iscato I'll try to help you with that - You have that line in your function: `select.val();` - You also know the actual value, but it's on the server side, so why won't you change it to `select.val("<?php echo $myValue; ?>");`?

Comment: If you have multiple selects then you can pass the value to the function: `var something = function(from_pallets, to_pallets, dbValue) { .. select.val(dbValue);  }` and pass it to the function `something(from_pallets, to_pallets, "<?php echo $myValue; ?>")`

Comment: @iscato even thought automatically loaded selected options can be set.

Comment: @AlonEitan i didn't think of recycling the function, it seems that is going to be it, but making the parameter as opcional and checking if it exists and  im gonna need to loop through each of the selects, i don't exactly know if like it is now it will select the different options for each one of them, i'll test it tomorrow, i appreciate your help.

Comment: @burhancerit they are loaded dinamycally with the value of the input number the client fills in the same page as the table.

Comment: @AlonEitan i made an update to give a little more context, as it is i can't do what you said, because that way i can only pass one value from the php and i need one for every select, i'm working on it, if i find the solution i will post the answer. oh, and that select.val() was there for nothing, it wasn't doing anything

Comment: @AlonEitan i find the way to do it, similar as the thing you proposed, i will shortly post the answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AlonEitan to helping me find a way to solve this

in the template i had a script that did something like this:

```
var init = function() {
someone.something('#total_pallets', '.pallets_assign');
};
```

changed to:

```
var init = function() {

    var option = [];

    <? foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
      <? for ($i = 1; $i <= count($product["boxes"]); $i++) { ?>
        option.push(<?=(somechecks ? $product["boxes"][$i]["which_pallet"] : false);?>);
        <? } ?>
    <? } ?>

    someone.something('#total_pallets', '.pallets_assign', option);
};
```

and in my js file i had this:

```
var someone = function() {
var something = function(from_pallets, to_pallets) {
    var qty = $(from_pallets);
    var select = $(to_pallets);
    var update = function() {
        select.empty();
        for (var i = 1; i <= qty.val(); i++) {
            select.append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
        }
    };

    qty.on('change', update);
    update();
}
});
```

which is now:

```
var someone = function() {
var something = function(from_pallets, to_pallets, option) {
    var qty = $(from_pallets);
    var select = $(to_pallets);
    var update = function() {
        select.empty();
        select.each(function(i) {
                for (var j = 1; j <= qty.val(); j++) {
                    $(this).append('<option value="' + j + '"' + (j == option[i] ? ' selected="selected"' : '') + '>' + j + '</option>');
                }
            });
    };

    qty.on('change', update);
    update();
}
});
```

It is a shame that in the beginning this got that many downvotes because i think is a cool way to solve this kind of issue and people will profit of this, but anyway.